# Is There any way to create Foreign key constraints with Conditions

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there any way to create relationship, between table with conditions as

I have 3 tables

1. quotations
2. other_quotation
3. cart

I want to be relatioship Like

**quotation** table

```
---
| id | service_id |
---
| 1  |  12        |
---
```

**other_quotation** table

```
---
| id | quotation_id | service_id |
---
| 1  |     1        |    15      |
```

**cart** table

```
---
| id | quotation_id | quotation_type |
---
| 1  |   1          |    0           |
---
| 2  |   1          |    1           |
---
```

I have created, Foreign key constraints between cart and quotation use `Id`and `quotation_id`, But I want relationship of cart with both table quotations and `other_quotation`, on behalf of `quotation_type`, if cart having `quotation_type 0` then check relation with quoation table else with `other_quoation` table,

If any suggestion, How I can do it Please let me know, I Want cascade on delete or on update.

If its not correct way to do this, Please let know the correct way

Thanks

Comment: No you cant. Simplest way to enforce this is in your application code. Do a validation while trying to Insert/Update. Else you can write Triggers.

Comment: Okay, That's is already implemented, I was asking for, if it is possible.